# How can I bind two controls in two different windows on wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to bind two controls like font size slider and text box, and each control is on different window on wpf, so how can I bind them?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: It is a university project, I can bind on the same window but I want to know how to bind between different windows or even if there are any other way than binding ? I need to change text size from slider control on other window ..

Comment: You will have to use the same ViewModel with a property like FontSize for both windows. Set it as the `DataContext` of the Windows and bind to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

**1)** Create a WPF project.

**2)** Change the contents of the `MainWindow.xaml` to the following (don't forget to correct the namespaces in all the code that I'm posting, for example in my code the namespace is `WpfApplication2`):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Settings Window" Click="SettingsWindowButton_OnClick"/>
        <Button Content="Bound Window" Click="BoundWindowButton_OnClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**3)** Change the contents of the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to the following:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    using System.Windows;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SettingsWindowButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var settingsWindow = new SettingsWindow();
            settingsWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
            settingsWindow.Show();
        }

        private void BoundWindowButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var boundWindow = new BoundWindow();
            boundWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
            boundWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**4)** Create a class named `ViewModel` in your project with the following code:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _fontSizeSetting = 10;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int FontSizeSetting
        {
            get { return _fontSizeSetting; }
            set
            {
                _fontSizeSetting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FontSizeSetting");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**5)** Add two new `Window`s to your project named `BoundWindow` and `SettingsWindow` with the following markup:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.BoundWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BoundWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox FontSize="{Binding FontSizeSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="test..."/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

-

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.SettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SettingsWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Slider Value="{Binding FontSizeSetting, Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="10" Maximum="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now everything should be working as expected. What you basically did was to create a view model to set as the `DataContext` of your `Window`s. They both bind to the `FontSizeSetting` property of your view model, and when you change it in one window, WPF binding system takes care of changing the other value automatically.